# searching using angular filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

Refer below code.

Using angular filter i can search friend.name or friend.phone or both but how to make search in string that combines both, like in below example code i want to make a search for "mary - 80" and it should display only one list element "Mary - 800-BIG-MARY".

How to do this, pls help me out.
Is it possible with using default angularjs filter??

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script> 
    </head>

<body ng-app="">
    <div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                     {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                     {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                     {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                     {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                     {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>

    <label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter: searchText">
        <span>{{friend.name}} - {{friend.phone}}</span>
    </li>
</body>
</html>
```

plunker link for same code: http://plnkr.co/edit/p7valhnDulHorw8xDYu8?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how angularJs filter works by default. If you want to filter by a specific combination of properties, then you have to implement your own filter function.
Like here https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-custom-angularjs-filters

super simple example

```
  $scope.customFilter = (item)=> {
    //TODO: Add your own properties here
    return item.someProperty == $scope.filterValue;
  };
```

html

```
<htmlElement ng-repeat="item in itemList | filter:customFilter"></htmlElement>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It is clear to me that i need to write a custom filter for what i ask, but are you sure it is not possible using default filter?

Comment: no, it is not possible. You want to search according to 2 properties, but the filter has single argument. You have to parse the filter value in order to be able to search by 2 different values in 2 different properties

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want

change the repeat:

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filterText:searchText">
```

and then add this filter

```
  app= angular.module("myApp",[]);

  app.filter("filterText",function(){
    return function(items,text){
      var result = [];
      text = text != undefined ? text : "";

      var words = text.split(" ");

      angular.forEach(items,function(v,i){

          allFound = true;
          angular.forEach(words,function(v2,i2){
             if((v.name+v.phone).toUpperCase().indexOf(v2.toUpperCase())==-1){
                allFound = false;
             }
          })
          if(allFound)
          result.push(v);

      });
       return result;
    }
  });
```

remember to add the ng-app

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
```

you dont need to use the '-' in your search, just use "Mary 800" or "Adam 555"